# How to call one class method from another class method

Tags: ruby

I am relatively new to Ruby and am having a hard time understanding class methods. If I have a class like the one below,

```
class Foo
  def self.a
  end

  def self.b
  end
end
```

How do I call `a` from `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use its name:

```
class Foo
  def self.a
    puts 'a'
  end

  def self.b
    puts 'b'
    a
  end
end

[23] pry(main)> Foo.a
a
=> nil
[24] pry(main)> Foo.b
b
a
=> nil
```

Comment: Yeah,,, so I completely misunderstood the error I was getting haha. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, recall that classes are modules with certain properties. Let's first look at modules. One built-in module is the [Math](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Math.html) module. You will see from the doc that `Math` has no instance methods (so there would be no point to include or prepend that module into a class); all of its methods are *module methods*. That means they are invoked with an *explicit receiver*: `Math.sqrt(10)`. `Math` is merely a library of *helper* methods, available for use by all modules (and hence, classes).

Let's add a module method to `Math`:

```
module Math
  def Math.sqr(x)
    x*x
  end
end

Math.sqr(3)
  #=> 9
```

Suppose we decided to change the name of this module to `Maths`. We would then have to rewrite this method:

```
module Maths
  def Maths.sqr(x)
    x*x
  end
end
```

If is for that reason module methods are generally defined `def self.method(...)`, as `self` equals the module in which the method is defined. That way, if the module name is changed the module methods don't have to be redefined.

Since classes are modules, *class methods* are just another name for *module methods* (though class methods are inherited by subclasses), and the foregoing applies to classes and class methods as well.

Like all methods, module methods are invoked by prefacing the method with its receiver. For example, `Math.sqrt(10)`. Similarly, like all methods, the method can be invoked without including its receiver (i.e., the receiver is *implicit*) if `self` equals its receiver at the time it is invoked. A module method's receiver equals `self` only when the method is invoked from within the module in which it was defined, outside a method, or from with another module method defined in the same module. For example, since `sqrt` is a module method in `Math`, I could write:

```
module Math
  def Math.sqrt_times_2(x)
    puts "self = #{self}"
    2 * sqrt(x)
  end
end

Math.sqrt_times_2(25)
  # self = Math
  #=> 10.0
```

Since classes are modules all of this applies to class methods as well, but this extends to subclasses as well, through inheritance. To invoke a class method `klass_method` defined in class `Klass`, we could invoke the method `Klass.klass(...)` (possibly followed by a block) from any class, but could (and should) drop the explicit receiver `Klass.` if it were invoked from within `Klass` or within a subclass of `Klass`. Here's an example.

```
class Klass
  def self.klass_method(n)
    puts "In klass_method, self = #{self}"
    2 * n
  end

  def self.other_klass_method(n)
    puts "In other_klass_method, self = #{self}"
    3 * klass_method(n)    
  end
end

class SubKlass < Klass
  def self.sub_klass_method(n)
    puts "In sub_klass_method, self = #{self}"
    5 * klass_method(n)
  end

  def sub_klass_instance_method(n)
    puts "In sub_klass_instance_method, self = #{self}"
    5 * self.class.klass_method(n)
  end
end
```

```
Klass.klass_method(2)
  # In klass_method, self = Klass
  #=> 4 
Klass.other_klass_method(3)
  # In other_klass_method, self = Klass
  # In klass_method, self = Klass
  #=> 18 
SubKlass.sub_klass_method(4)
  # In sub_klass_method, self = SubKlass
  # In klass_method, self = SubKlass
  #=> 40 

si = SubKlass.new
  # In sub_klass_instance_method, self = #<SubKlass:0x0000586729649c70>
  # In klass_method, self = SubKlass
si.sub_klass_instance_method(3)
  # In klass_method, self = SubKlass
  #=> 30
```

The last statement above shows that, to invoke a class method from within an instance method, the method's receiver must be set equal to the class in which the instance method is defined.